# z-index is not respected during a css3 transitions

Tags: jquery, z-index, css-transitions, css-animations

I made a gallery with CSS3 and jQuery (in here: http://dev.crosscode.no/artgallery/) but I have a problem:

When the first right photo replace the main photo (during the transition) the second right photo looks over the first right photo but the zIndex of the first right photo is 650 and the zIndex of the second right photo is 600. Does anybody know why it happens?

I'm using `all 0.75s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1) 0s` as transition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks right to me (Chrome 22, Win7). Nice gallery by the way.

Answer (score 0):

currently trying to solve similar problem not gallery but a layer -> z-index working wrong in all 4 browsers(ff,ie,chr,saf). What is your order of divs? mine is:

```
<div #container>
  <div .layer>
     <div .wrap2>
        <div .wrap1>
           <img #1>
           <span .gizmo1>
           <span .gizmo2>

  <div .layer>
     <div .wrap2>
        <div .wrap1>
           <img #2>
           <span .gizmo1>
           <span .gizmo2>
```

ISSUES:
1) when IMG#2 has higher z-index, still IMG#1 is showing on top
2) when first layer's .gizmo1, .gizmo are hidden, none of fst layer's elements has z-index set AND second layer's .gizmo1, .gizmo2 has z-index 1000, still IMG#1 is showing on top of everything.. (event if set img#1 z-index to 200/2000 -- neither is respected)

ussed CSS effects: "transform: rotate(60deg)" on .wrap1 of each layer -- nothing else

(using, jQuery.1.10.2, jQuery UI.1.10.3)

seems to be really strange,
What am I missing?

-- EDIT: The Z-index Issue appears ONLY since I add transform property to some of the .wrap div! That means: When app is started, and no transform: is present.. then z-indexes working fine!